# How to make a post request a file along with JSON data in Node.JS using a request module

Tags: json, node.js, post, request, sails.js

In python below, my code is working for this problem but I'm finding difficulty in Node.JS with this request module.

This is my python code :

```
inputData = {
  "datasetName": "dataset44",
  "typeOfDataset": "TS",
  "userID": "c0fe211c_8c41_459a_9019_19d98111ed92"
}
fileName = 'out.csv'
files = {
  'json': (None, json.dumps(inputData), 'application/json'),
  'file': (os.path.basename(fileName), open(fileName, 'rb'),
    'application/octet-stream')
}
```

What I'm trying here:

```
var fileData = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json , application/octet- 
    stream,
    multipart / form - data ' }

    var files = {
      'json': {
        "datasetName": dataSetName,
        "typeOfDataSet": "TS",
        "userID": req.session.userSourceID
      },
      'file': fileData
    }
    // Configure the request
    var options = {
      url: ' http://xx.xx.xx.x:x/x1/createx',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      json: files
    }

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `multipart/related` in Node.js. See https://github.com/request/request#multipartrelated.

Comment: This looks helpful but I'm confused in syntax .How to set file with different content-type and json data with different content-type. And both are in one object.